# Match Destination Formatting Excel 2016

Tags: excel-2016

Using Windows, I have followed the directions to add Match Destination Formatting to Excel in the tool bar, but it goes gray when I attempted to copy and paste from one excel spreadsheet to another. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The option to match destination formatting is only available when the data to be pasted comes from another application, like Word. If you copy and paste between two Excel workbooks, you can use **Paste Special > Formulas** to achieve the same effect, i.e. keep the destination formats instead of overwriting them.